# itext7 stamp and redact annotation not working

Tags: java, itext, itext7

The code is below. It is adapted from a standard itext 7 example to add a PdfRedactAnnotation. The link annotation works, but the stamp and redact ones don't work. The PDF that I'm using is linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jh0e4ttr3q1ne9/calendar_2018-08-04_2018-08-19.pdf?dl=0). Anyone know why this won't work? Is is something about the PDF?

My end goal is to put some white rectangles over portions of the text so that the text doesn't show up when printing.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.action.PdfAction;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfLinkAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfRedactAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfStampAnnotation;

public class AddRotatedAnnotation {
    static final String SRC = Paths.get("calendar_2018-08-04_2018-08-19.pdf").toString();
    static final String DEST = Paths.get("calendar_clean.pdf").toString();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new AddRotatedAnnotation().manipulatePdf(DEST);
    }

    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));

        PdfAction action = PdfAction.createURI("http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html");
        Rectangle linkLocation1 = new Rectangle(30, 770, 90, 30);
        PdfAnnotation link1 = new PdfLinkAnnotation(linkLocation1)
                .setHighlightMode(PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT)
                .setAction(action)
                .setColor(ColorConstants.RED.getColorValue());
        pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(link1);

        Rectangle linkLocation2 = new Rectangle(30, 670, 30, 90);
        PdfAnnotation link2 = new PdfRedactAnnotation(linkLocation2)
                .setColor(ColorConstants.BLACK.getColorValue());
        pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(link2);

        Rectangle linkLocation3 = new Rectangle(150, 770, 90, 30);
        PdfAnnotation stamp1 = new PdfStampAnnotation(linkLocation3)
                .setStampName(new PdfName("Confidential"))
                .setContents("Landscape").setColor(ColorConstants.BLACK.getColorValue());
        pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp1);

        Rectangle linkLocation4 = new Rectangle(150, 670, 90, 90);
        PdfAnnotation stamp2 = new PdfStampAnnotation(linkLocation4)
                .setStampName(new PdfName("Confidential"))
                .setContents("Portrait")
                .put(PdfName.Rotate, new PdfNumber(90));
        pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp2);

        Rectangle linkLocation5 = new Rectangle(250, 670, 90, 90);
        PdfAnnotation stamp3 = new PdfStampAnnotation(linkLocation5)
                .setStampName(new PdfName("Confidential"))
                .setContents("Portrait")
                .put(PdfName.Rotate, new PdfNumber(45));
        pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp3);

        pdfDoc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but the stamp and redact ones don't work."* - in which way don't they work? Does your program get stuck in that code? Does it throw some exception? Does the computer explode?

Comment: The stamp is not visible and the redact doesn't cover any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running the OP's code the problems are apparent:

- in a PDF viewer the annotations are essentially transparent; depending on the viewer they can be selected or their pop-ups appear;
- in a print-out the annotation are completely absent.

These issues can be fixed individually:

- the annotations need appearance streams for normal display and
- they need to have their respective **PRINT** flag set to be visible in print-outs.

I enhanced your annotations `link2` and `stamp1` accordingly as `link2x` and `stamp1x`:

```
Rectangle linkLocation2x = new Rectangle(150, 470, 30, 90);
PdfAnnotation link2x = new PdfRedactAnnotation(linkLocation2x)
        .setColor(ColorConstants.BLACK.getColorValue());
PdfFormXObject formN = new PdfFormXObject(linkLocation2x);
PdfCanvas canvasN = new PdfCanvas(formN, pdfDoc);
canvasN.setFillColorGray(1)
       .rectangle(linkLocation2x.getX(), linkLocation2x.getY(), linkLocation2x.getWidth(), linkLocation2x.getHeight())
       .fill();
link2x.setNormalAppearance(formN.getPdfObject());
link2x.setFlag(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(link2x);

Rectangle linkLocation3x = new Rectangle(150, 370, 90, 30);
PdfAnnotation stamp1x = new PdfStampAnnotation(linkLocation3x)
        .setStampName(new PdfName("Confidential"))
        .setContents("Landscape").setColor(ColorConstants.BLACK.getColorValue());
formN = new PdfFormXObject(linkLocation3x);
canvasN = new PdfCanvas(formN, pdfDoc);
canvasN.setFillColorGray(1)
       .rectangle(linkLocation3x.getX(), linkLocation3x.getY(), linkLocation3x.getWidth(), linkLocation3x.getHeight())
       .fill();
stamp1x.setNormalAppearance(formN.getPdfObject());
stamp1x.setFlag(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
pdfDoc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp1x);
```

---

If you did this not only for printing but also for distribution of the electronic PDF, you should add redaction annotations **and then run redaction,** e.g. using the iText 7 [pdfSweep add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfSweep), to actually remove that information and not merely cover it.

Comment: This covers the text, but it shows up white instead of black. Although link2x does cover the text as I wanted. It is unexpected that I'd need an annotation and a canvas to the annotation. I would have expected the annotation to do that itself.

Comment: *"but it shows up white instead of black"* - I've used white color to fill the area:  `canvasN.setFillColorGray(1)`. For black use `canvasN.setFillColorGray(0)` instead.

Comment: @Jon I used white because in your question you said *"My end goal is to put some **white** rectangles over portions of the text so that the text doesn't show up when printing."*

Comment: @Jon *"I would have expected the annotation to do that itself."* - The problem with that is that **it is not clear which annotation appearance a user wants**. *Redaction annotations* themselves are not meant to *hide* the data to redact, they are meant to *mark* it so that an actual redaction tool (e.g. pdfSweep) knows which content to remove. Marking data appearance-wise may or may not hide it, it might even frame or otherwise emphasize it...